# How to select maximum two values using LIMIT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the database in `MySQL`  like this

```
id employee_id  salary
1    1          10000
2    2          20000
3    3          10000
4    4          40000
5    5          30000
```

I want to select the `maximum two salary by using LIMIT`.So how to select that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just sort your results in descending order of salary and limit the resultset as desired:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca8b9/1/0).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  employee_id,
  salary 
From
  employee 
order by salary desc 
limit 2 ;
```